# Can I use manifests to specify an optional dependency on a COM server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, com, manifest, side-by-side

I'd like to use manifests to specify a dependency on a COM server ([reg-free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)).

The consumer application will mostly work fine without the COM server - only something like 1,7% of its functionality uses the COM server. So with plain old `regsvr32` it would start and work fine until the user would do something that would trigger `CoCreateInstance()` call and at that point the consumer would get an error message.

Now I've played with manifests for a while and it looks like the consumer wouldn't even start unless the COM server assembly it depends on is present in the file system. That's no good.

I added the "addiditional manifest" with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity
              type="win32"
              name="TheComServer.X"
              version="1.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Is there a way to use reg-free COM with manifests and make the dependency optional - so that the consumer program starts and works fine until `CoCreateInstance()` is actually called?

Comment: Hey, did you figure that out? Same problem here. It's very annoying, the application simply doesn't run if the dependency is not present because it's optional (like a plugin or something).

Comment: @natenho Nope, ended up working without manifest dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to provide at least the manifest for the reg-free COM assemblies.

The application manifest references the assemblies the application wants - the component manifests are processed at application startup - and specify the com objects the assembly exports.

They *have* to be specified as the activation context is loaded.

You can use the activation context API to manually create an activation context and load assemblies into it - and then ensure that that context is current when you try to CoCreateInstance.

Comment: Yes, I understand that they have to be specified. But can they be specified as optional?

Comment: Whatever goes into the process manifest is resolved on application startup, and there's no concept of an optional dependency. So remove this information from the process manifest, and create a new manifest with this info. At the time you want to call CoCreateInstance, you can then load up this second manifest and activate it manually using the activation context API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374151(VS.85).aspx all the while handling the case where the second manifest is not present.